# If HTML response is null, display alternate content

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

My api call returns html, but if that html is empty e.g. I get a console html response of "", I want to display a default message using knockout. So I'm guessing that it needs to recognise that "" is empty and then display my alternate content.
**View model -**

```
    var MyText = ko.observable(); 

    var company = shell.authenticatedCompany();
    hazibo.helpTextGet(company.name, company.userName, company.password).then(function (data) {
        MyText(data);  
    });


return {
    MyText: MyText
```

};

**View -**

```
<section class="help-text">
    <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="flex-item" data-bind="html: MyText">This is my alternate message if the html response is ""</div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways you could go about it. Personally I like to keep as much code out of the markup as possible so I would check your response data in the api callback and set it there. No need to create messy looking data bindings if you just update the observable appropriately.

```
hazibo.helpTextGet(company.name, company.userName, company.password).then(function (data) {
    if(!data) {
        MyText("This is my alternate message...");
    }else{
        MyText(data);
    }
});
```

If you need to preserve what the api call actually returned you could place the logic in a computed instead, and bind to that.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to use a computed observable to determine which set of html to display:

https://jsfiddle.net/dw1284/ucnewzwo/

**HTML:**

```
<section class="help-text">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item" data-bind="html: ItemHtml()"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

  // Html populated from API call
  self.MyText = ko.observable('');

  // Default Html
  self.Default = ko.observable('This is my alternate message if the html response is ""');

  // Computed observable chooses which HTML to display (bind this to view)
  self.ItemHtml = ko.computed(function() {
    if (!self.MyText() || self.MyText() === '') {
        return self.Default();
    } else {
        return self.MyText();
    }
  });
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```